# Use a mesh as a path with correct tilt information for use with "duplicate frames"

Tags: python, mesh

The first picture shows the mesh, I'm looking for a way use the duplicate frames feature to make the object follow that "path" as it is shown in the second picture with an actual path.

[image: Example mesh]

[image: Example result]

I guess the task is mainly to convert the mesh into a path with the correct tilt information but I'm open for every solution.

Comment: Taking Daniel's script into 2.8, the curve it is building is whacky. Not much of a python user, (all I did was change the last couple lines of code). I hope there is some sort of answer/alternative to transferring mesh normals to CV [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY5ii.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY5ii.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to write a quick and dirty python script  that works **for my specific case** with almost no python knowledge or knowledge about Blender's API.

Therefore I'm sure it could be optimized for faster execution or more generalised and also the calculated tilt is only correct for paths where the tilting is parallel to the xy-plane.

I think the latter could be quite easily fixed with some more simple math that takes the pitch of the path into account but this is not required in my case and therefore I did not make my head around it.

```
import bpy
import math

def vMid( obj, edge ):
    vRes = obj.vertices[edge.vertices[0]].co+obj.vertices[edge.vertices[1]].co;
    vRes *= 0.5;
    return vRes;

def vTilt( obj, edge ):
    #order might have to be changed or automatically detected for certain meshes
    v1 = obj.vertices[edge.vertices[1]].co
    v2 = obj.vertices[edge.vertices[0]].co

    #only correct for tilting in xy-plane
    z = v1.z - v2.z
    l = math.sqrt( (v1.x - v2.x)**2 + (v1.y - v2.y)**2 )
    return math.atan(z/l)

def distance( v1, v2 ):
    vret = v1 - v2
    return vret.length

def addCoords( edge, edges, usedEdges, outputs ):
    curPos = vMid(me, edge)
    curTilt = vTilt(me, edge)
    output = curPos,curTilt
    outputs.append(output)
    usedEdges.append(edge)
    dist = 9999.9
    nextEdge = edge;
    for next in edges:
        #I'm sure this could be optimized somehow
        if next in usedEdges:
            continue
        nextPos = vMid(me, next)
        newDist = distance(nextPos, curPos)
        if newDist < dist:
            nextEdge = next
            dist = newDist
    if nextEdge != edge:
        addCoords( nextEdge, edges, usedEdges, outputs )

ob = bpy.context.object

if ob.type != 'MESH':
    raise TypeError("Active object is not a Mesh")

ob.update_from_editmode()

me = ob.data
usedEdges=[]    
outputs=[]

addCoords( me.edges[0], me.edges, usedEdges, outputs)

# create the Curve Datablock
curveData = bpy.data.curves.new(ob.name+'_curve', type='CURVE')
curveData.dimensions = '3D'
curveData.resolution_u = 2
curveData.twist_mode = 'Z_UP'

# map coords to spline
polyline = curveData.splines.new('POLY')
polyline.points.add(len(outputs)-1)
polyline.use_cyclic_u = 1
for i, output in enumerate(outputs):
    coord,tilt = output
    x,y,z = coord
    polyline.points[i].co = (x, y, z, 1)
    polyline.points[i].tilt = tilt

# create Object
curveOB = bpy.data.objects.new(ob.name+'_Curve', curveData)

# attach to scene and validate context
scn = bpy.context.scene
scn.objects.link(curveOB)
scn.objects.active = curveOB
```

**I've changed the script** it does now uses the polygons instead of the edges to get the tilt information and therefore it works also with sections that are tilted and not parallel to the xy plane:

```
import bpy
import math
import mathutils

#calculates tilt according to face's normal and path direction from this face
def fTilt( face, v ):
    #normal vector of path
    n = mathutils.Vector((-v.z*v.x / (v.x**2 + v.y**2), -v.z*v.y / (v.x**2 + v.y**2), 1))
    t = face.normal
    val = (n.x*t.x+n.y*t.y+n.z*t.z)/t.length/n.length
    if val>1:
        val = 1
    if val<-1:
        val = -1
    return math.acos(val)

#distance between v1 v2
def distance( v1, v2 ):
    vret = v1 - v2
    return vret.length

#add coordinates and tilt informations to outputs (=coordinates,tilt)
def addCoords( face, faces, usedFaces, outputs ):
    curPos = face.center
    usedFaces.append(face)
    dist = 9999.9
    nextFace = face
    nextPos = curPos
    for next in faces:
        #could maybe optimized for faster execution
        if next in usedFaces:
            continue
        newPos = next.center
        newDist = distance(newPos, curPos)
        if newDist < dist:
            nextFace = next
            nextPos = newPos
            dist = newDist
    if nextFace != face:
        tilt = 0
        if(nextPos != curPos):
            tilt = fTilt(face, nextPos - curPos)
        output = curPos,tilt
        outputs.append(output)
        addCoords( nextFace, faces, usedFaces, outputs )

ob = bpy.context.object

if ob.type != 'MESH':
    raise TypeError("Active object is not a Mesh")

ob.update_from_editmode()

me = ob.data
usedFaces=[]  
outputs=[]

addCoords(me.polygons[0], me.polygons, usedFaces, outputs)  

# create the Curve Datablock
curveData = bpy.data.curves.new(ob.name+'_curve', type='CURVE')
curveData.dimensions = '3D'
curveData.resolution_u = 2
curveData.twist_mode = 'Z_UP'

# map coords to spline
polyline = curveData.splines.new('POLY')
polyline.points.add(len(outputs)-1)
polyline.use_cyclic_u = 1
for i, output in enumerate(outputs):
    coord,tilt = output
    x,y,z = coord
    polyline.points[i].co = (x, y, z, 1)
    polyline.points[i].tilt = tilt

# create Object
curveOB = bpy.data.objects.new(ob.name+'_Curve', curveData)

# attach to scene and validate context
scn = bpy.context.scene
scn.objects.link(curveOB)
scn.objects.active = curveOB
```

**One more update:** This fixes a important bug that only applied the tilt correctly into one tilt direction

```
import bpy
import math
import mathutils

#calculates tilt according to face's normal and path direction from this face
def fTilt( face, v ):
    #normal vector of path
    n = mathutils.Vector((-v.z*v.x / (v.x**2 + v.y**2), -v.z*v.y / (v.x**2 + v.y**2), 1))
    nf = face.normal
    t = mathutils.Vector((
        v.y*n.z - v.z*n.y,
        v.z*n.x - v.x*n.z,
        v.x*n.y - v.y*n.x
    ))
    val = (nf.x*t.x+nf.y*t.y+nf.z*t.z)/nf.length/t.length
    if val>1:
        val = 1
    if val<-1:
        val = -1
    return math.asin(val)

#distance between v1 v2
def distance( v1, v2 ):
    vret = v1 - v2
    return vret.length

#add coordinates and tilt informations to outputs (=coordinates,tilt)
def addCoords( face, faces, usedFaces, outputs ):
    curPos = face.center
    usedFaces.append(face)
    dist = 9999.9
    nextFace = face
    nextPos = curPos
    for next in faces:
        #could maybe optimized for faster execution
        if next in usedFaces:
            continue
        newPos = next.center
        newDist = distance(newPos, curPos)
        if newDist < dist:
            nextFace = next
            nextPos = newPos
            dist = newDist
    if nextFace != face:
        tilt = 0
        if(nextPos != curPos):
            tilt = fTilt(face, nextPos - curPos)
        output = curPos,tilt
        outputs.append(output)
        addCoords( nextFace, faces, usedFaces, outputs )

ob = bpy.context.object

if ob.type != 'MESH':
    raise TypeError("Active object is not a Mesh")

ob.update_from_editmode()

me = ob.data
usedFaces=[]  
outputs=[]

addCoords(me.polygons[0], me.polygons, usedFaces, outputs)  

# create the Curve Datablock
curveData = bpy.data.curves.new(ob.name+'_curve', type='CURVE')
curveData.dimensions = '3D'
curveData.resolution_u = 2
curveData.twist_mode = 'Z_UP'

# map coords to spline
polyline = curveData.splines.new('POLY')
polyline.points.add(len(outputs)-1)
polyline.use_cyclic_u = 1
for i, output in enumerate(outputs):
    coord,tilt = output
    x,y,z = coord
    polyline.points[i].co = (x, y, z, 1)
    polyline.points[i].tilt = tilt

# create Object
curveOB = bpy.data.objects.new(ob.name+'_Curve', curveData)

# attach to scene and validate context
scn = bpy.context.scene
scn.objects.link(curveOB)
scn.objects.active = curveOB
```

A test file:

[image]

Comment: Could you post your testfile?

Answer (score 2):

- First create a loop cut in the middle of your Path,

[image]

- Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> while the loop cut is selected to select everything appart from this exact edge and <kbd>delete</kbd>. Or if you want to keep the path you have to just duplicate this loop cut and **Separate it by Selection**, using <kbd>P</kbd> key,

[image]

- After that you have to convert this edge into a Curve, to do that press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > **Curve from Mesh/Text**.

[image]

- Now you have to get your model of the planch,

[image]

- Give it an **Array** Modifier, and set the spacing between each planch as well as the number of the planches to fit the Curve.

[image]

[image]

- Finally apply the **Aray** Modifier and add a **Curve** Modifier, then choose the Curve *(it is propably going to be under the name of PLANE)*

[image]

[image]

**The Result**

[image]

Comment: While all you have said is correct, I don't think this method can solve the "tilting" problem

Comment: Yes the actual problem is how to consider the tilt information. By using the curve modifier the mesh gets also deformed which is not wanted in this case. I've just tilted the path manually at the closest object to make the desired result a bit more obvious: [http://imgur.com/Z5FQcGZ](http://imgur.com/Z5FQcGZ)